# Why the background color dont change?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i want to change the body Background color on specific time  with JavaScript   but the code don't seems to work! Why?

```
function changebg(){
    var date= new Date().getHours();

    if(date >= 21 && date <=6){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
    }
}

changebg();
```

Comment: `(date >= 21 && date <=6)` this will never be `true`  because no hour is greater than or equal to 21 and less than or equal to 6 at same time

Comment: `(date >= 9 && date <=6)` will also never be `true`

Comment: I did a rollback on your question as it actually changed logic *after* answers have been given. We tend to keep the answer original, dont fix it after you've gotten the answer so that others may learn from the original problem (which, in this case isn't the best example)

Comment: @Martijn sorry wont do it anymore :)

Comment: No worries, we all have to get used to the SE ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try with `date >= 21 || date <= 6` instead.

```js
changeBackground();

function changeBackground() {
  const currentHour = new Date().getHours();

  if(currentHour >= 21 || currentHour <= 6) {
      //document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
      console.log('now you can change the color here for night');
  } else {
      console.log('default color');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i was really dumb*

Comment: As this is the marked answer I'll post it here: `date` is a not a good var name. `currentHour` would be better :)

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the comment, just updated and looks better I agree. Also I've changed to `const` instead of having `var` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function changebg(){
    var date= new Date().getHours();


if(date >= 9 || date <=6 ){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";

}else{
    //
}

}
changebg();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably want something like this:

```
function changebg(){
  var hour = new Date().getHours();

  if (hour >= 21 || hour <= 6) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
  }else{
    // todo
  }
}
changebg();
```